# How to configure proxychains the right way?

Tags: networking, dns, proxy, tor

I configured proxychains following a couple tutorials on the web which were pretty much all the same, as they showed the configuration using Tor service. The problem I'm having is that my DNS is being leaked as well as my real IP address. When I start Firefox with proxychains Google sometimes shows I'm on the other side of the globe but still shows my real IP address when prompted for captcha and other times it shows the city I live in. I did a [DNS leak test](https://dnsleaktest.com/)  as well which didn't show my location or network provider at all, but on [WhatIsMyIpAddress](https://whatismyipaddress.com/) it showed all of my info.
I use Firefox with no additional proxy settings in the browser. I tried using free proxies, but every single one of them, regardless if HTTP, SOCKS4-5 gets timed out. I don't really want to use free proxies, I'd rather use the Tor service but I can't get it to work properly. The distro I use is Mint 20.3 (Una).

The proxychains.conf file:

```
# proxychains.conf  VER 3.1
#
#        HTTP, SOCKS4, SOCKS5 tunneling proxifier with DNS.
#       

# The option below identifies how the ProxyList is treated.
# only one option should be uncommented at time,
# otherwise the last appearing option will be accepted
#
dynamic_chain
#
# Dynamic - Each connection will be done via chained proxies
# all proxies chained in the order as they appear in the list
# at least one proxy must be online to play in chain
# (dead proxies are skipped)
# otherwise EINTR is returned to the app
#
#strict_chain
#
# Strict - Each connection will be done via chained proxies
# all proxies chained in the order as they appear in the list
# all proxies must be online to play in chain
# otherwise EINTR is returned to the app
#
#random_chain
#
# Random - Each connection will be done via random proxy
# (or proxy chain, see  chain_len) from the list.
# this option is good to test your IDS :)

# Make sense only if random_chain
#chain_len = 2

# Quiet mode (no output from library)
#quiet_mode

Proxy DNS requests - no leak for DNS data
proxy_dns

# Some timeouts in milliseconds
tcp_read_time_out 15000
tcp_connect_time_out 8000

# ProxyList format
#       type  host  port [user pass]
#       (values separated by 'tab' or 'blank')
#
#
#        Examples:
#
#               socks5  192.168.67.78   1080    lamer   secret
#               http    192.168.89.3    8080    justu   hidden
#               socks4  192.168.1.49    1080
#               http    192.168.39.93   8080    
#
#
#       proxy types: http, socks4, socks5
#        ( auth types supported: "basic"-http  "user/pass"-socks )
#
#
[ProxyList]
# add proxy here ...
# meanwile
# defaults set to "tor"
socks4  127.0.0.1 9050
socks5 127.0.0.1 9050
```

Answer (score 1):

kind of a newbie here but i noticed a typo.
when you write socks5 127.0.0.1 9050, instead of hitting spacebar between socks5 and 127.0.0.1 9050, you should hit tab instead.
also, I would comment the "Proxy DNS requests - no leak for DNS data" and only leave "proxy_dns" uncommented as well.

i don't know if this helps, but i made the same mistakes a while ago - and when I noticed that and changed, it helped me!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/439770)

Comment: Looking at [the proxychains code](https://github.com/haad/proxychains/blob/master/src/libproxychains.c#L217), it seems as if they use `sscanf()` to parse the text read from the configuration file.  This ignores whitespace characters, so using spaces or tabs makes no difference.  The missing comment character that you mention is probably a bigger issue.